# Passing environment variables to `subprocess.call`

Tags: python, subprocess, environment-variables

I have a bash script `my_script.sh` containing a line like `./my_python_script.py 2>&1` and within the Python script is contained the lines

```
import os
from util import do_something
project_dir = os.environ["PROJECT_DIR"]
do_something(spider_name="my_spider", project_dir=project_dir, data_dir="tmp/")
```

where `do_something` is something like

```
import subprocess
def do_something(spider_name, project_dir, data_dir):
  subprocess.call(["scrapy", "crawl", spider_name, 
    "--set", "FEED_URI=%s%s%s" % (project_dir, data_dir, spider_name+".json"),
  cwd=project_dir+"scrapers/"+spider_name+"/")
```

I'm calling `my_script.sh` in a cron job like so:

```
0 13 * * * . /home/ubuntu/.profile && cd $HOME/project_dir/ && ./my_script.sh > logs/daily_$CURR_DATE.log 2>&1
```

My problem is that the top level script is able to see the environment passed to it, but `do_something` is somehow not able to use it, reporting that

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./my_python_script.py", line 19, in <module>
    project_dir=project_dir, data_dir="tmp/")
  File "/home/ubuntu/project_dir/util/util.py", line 41, in 
do_something
    cwd=project_dir+"scrapers/"+spider_name+"/")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 523, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1343, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

The directory containing the Scrapy project does, in fact, exist, and I'm able to run `my_script.sh` manually without problem.  If I do a

```
print os.listdir(project_dir+"scrapers/"+spider_name+"/")
```

right before the call to `subprocess.call` I can see the complete contents of the project's directory.

What is going on here?  Why isn't `subprocess` able to change directories when I'm calling the script from a cronjob, but is able to when I run the script manually?  I'm really at a loss.  Thanks in advance for any insight.

Comment: Does changing the cronjob to use the bash shell change the result: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94456/how-to-change-cron-shell-sh-to-bash

Comment: @AnilVaitla Yes, I tried that with no effect.  I think it's not a cron issue, but rather a subprocess issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem turned out to be that `subprocess.call` couldn't find `cd` when invoked as I wrote, and hence could not make use of the `cwd` option.  Prepending

```
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin
```

to my crontab, or calling `subprocess.call` with the flag `shell=True`, brought `cd` into scope and fixed the issue.

Comment: `cd` is not an executable (how could it be?), it's a shell built-in.

Comment: Nice, yeah I think shell=True would do it. I feel I have gone through that discovery in the past as well. Good to hear it works for you!